# Most elegant way of turning bits on and off

Tags: c

I've got a register which can either be 0x02 or 0x01 (0010 or 0001). What is the most elegant way of setting the bits in a single operation? E.g. if the register is currently 0x02, I need to turn off bit 2 and turn on bit 1.

Many thanks

Comment: Simply assigning the value to the register isn't enough? xors and shifts may look cool and fast, but they make your code harder to understand.

Comment: It's embedded and simply assigning a value doesn't seem to modify the register, only bitwise operators.

Comment: Consider posting an example code, to avoid misinterpretations.

Comment: John, that appears to make no sense - if assigning (store) didn't work, neither would bitwise operations (load, modify, ***store***).

Answer (score 1):

`x ^= 3` changes 1 to 2 and changes 2 to 1. `^` performs an exclusive or (XOR) operation.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is to define a structure that uses bit fields. Sadly this is rarely appropriate when dealing with hardware registers (e.g. order of bits in a bit-field isn't well defined, etc).

Without bitfields; use "and with compliment" (e.g. `x = x & ~ 2;` or `x &= ~2;`) to clear bits and "or" (e.g. `x = x | 1;` or `x |= 1;`) to set bits.

If you know the previous value you can optimize further. For example, if you know the previous value is 0x02 then you can just set a new value (e.g. `x = 0x01;   // It was 0x02` or maybe `x = (0x02 & ~2) | 1;` so compiler will work out the constant for you but the source code still reflects how the constant was determined).

Note that it's not possible to do it in a single operation unless you do know something about the previous value. For example, if you know that the previous value will have bit 0 clear and bit 1 set but don't know anything about the other bits (and need to preserve the other bits), then you can decrement (`x--;   // Clear bit 2, set bit 1`) or use exclusive OR.